# Not able to redirect to another webpage in my project

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, web

I have a form:

`<form id="formId" onsubmit="addStudentData()"></form>`

And javascript function(find **HERE HERE HERE**) :

```
function addStudentData() {
let name = document.getElementById('sname').value;
let id = document.getElementById('sid').value;
let year = document.getElementById('syear').value;
let stream = document.getElementById('sstream').value;

/* Making a JSON object using the form values */
let studentObj = { 'name': name, 'year': year, 'stream': stream };

/* Pushing record to sessionStorage after stringify JSON Object*/
sessionStorage.setItem(id, JSON.stringify(studentObj));

/* Redirecting back to home page*/

**// HERE HERE HERE**
window.location.href = "index.html"
}
```

I don't understand why my javascript function is not opening 'index.html' after storing the data in sessionStorage.
Also, if you can, state another way to do it.

Comment: Are there any errors in F12 dev tools (either console or network tabs?).

Comment: no there are no errors

Comment: have you tried,  window.open("index.html",'_self',false);

Comment: window.open()  too not working, and dev tools not showing any errors.

Comment: What does sessionStorage.setItem do?  Have you tried putting a console.log() after that line to verify it's returning and not failing?

Comment: Yeah, sessionStorage.setItemI() is working fine, it is storing the JSON object into sessionStorage. But when I am adding console.log('sample') after sessionStorage.setItem(), then log output just blinks and then the same page reopens, although I am redirecting it to different page.

Comment: just try to comment out everything from that function except for window.location.href = "index.html"; and see what happens. What browser are you using?

Comment: It is not working even after commenting all except window.location.href ="index.html".

Comment: try writing return false; at the end of your function..

Comment: I have tried return false before, it hadn't work.

Comment: You may need to set up a demo that shows this problem because it's not evident from your code and comments.

Comment: After pressing submit button URL changes to : ile:///Y:/webUCA/ecmaScript6%20project/student-portal-es6/newItem.html?sname=Ashutoh&sid=22&syear=514&sstream=CS     Where sname,sid etc. are fields of the same form.

Comment: is your page, "index.html" located in the same folder which the current form html page is located?

Comment: Have you tried adding in `event.preventDefault()` on the form itself? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-code-to-stop-form-submission#answer-8664680

Comment: both these web pages are in the same directory. Also for a diagrammatical view of my problem go to  : https://drive.google.com/open?id=16VfWOBJ-GDHibIcslmUsFPw-0TdVLRWj

Comment: Adding event.preventDefault() will prevent my form from submission..That will not fulfill my thing.

Comment: Have you tried window.location.replace("index.html") ?

Comment: try  onsubmit = "return addStudentData()" 
and inside addStudentData return false;

Comment: because `index.html` is not a website. Try `http://localhost/index.html` or something to that effect.

Comment: window.location.replace("index.html"); also not working, and replacing index.html with locahost/index.html won't work because I am not hosting my website over the local server, these are just two web pages in the same directory.

Comment: Also, another button in the navbar is working fine if I click on it, which says <a href="index.html">Home</a>. But it is not working, I think form submission in causing some problem.

Comment: Something was wrong with the browser, it's now working with the same statements. I couldn't find the problem until now. But happy it's working. Thanks for the help everyone.